# Pupil Detection in eye images using python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I need to mark a pupil in an image like this of the eye. I have written this code
[image: Eye Image]

```
img_name='6.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(img_name)
image_copy_new=cv2.imread(img_name)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
plt.imshow(thresholded,cmap="gray")
```

This produces output like this -

[image: Threshold]

Then I searched for the contours in the images and tried to find only the most circular one in the image through this code

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image_copy = np.zeros_like(image)  # create a new emtpy image
for cnt in contours:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.04 * peri, True)
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    ar = w / float(h)
    if w*h > 20 and 0.9 < ar < 1.1:  # filtering condition
        cv2.drawContours(image, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)
```

While this produces great results in some cases where the eyes are in front facing direction but in other cases(like this one) it completely fails. I have tried many other things like **"hough transform, different morphs"** but I'm not able to tackle this problem. 
The images are of only eyes and **not the whole face else dlibs face detection would've worked** 
The cases where this code works is
[image: Working case]

Thanks for taking time and helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some blurring, erosion and dilation may help. Eroding will remove very small features, like the noise around the eyelashes, and dilation will bring any surviving points back up to size. By tweaking the erosion and dilation sizes, you should be able to get rid of most of the noise and make that center pupil look much better.

Here's an example of how I would do this:

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_in, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    erosion_size = 10
    dilate_size = 8
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (erosion_size, erosion_size)))
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (dilate_size, dilate_size)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The problem is that the eyebrow area and the pupil have the same black threshold value and even after erosion and dilation most of the eyebrows remain causing the problem in circle detection in contours.

Comment: In the above case with this method. There is again false positive of eyebrow.